# How to turn off opt-out feature in Twilio

Tags: twilio

I am working on a project that calls Twilio API to send SMS to client. In our project we would like to manage our own opt-out list instead of using Twilio's. In Twilio settings, I am not seems able to uncheck (turn off) the build-in opt-out feature. Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You are looking for the [Advanced Opt Out settings which are described in this article](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360034798533-Getting-Started-with-Advanced-Opt-Out-for-Messaging-Services).

> Advanced Opt-Out lets Messaging Services users customize and modify the STOP, UNSUBSCRIBE, HELP and more opt-in and opt-out keywords and standard replies for their services. Users can add and remove keywords, languages, and the response text for each Messaging Service. Previously, Twilio automatically replied to all opt-in/out keyword messages with our default responses.

The gist is, you need your number to be part of a [messaging service](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/services), and once it is, you can edit the settings for opt outs within that messaging service.

Comment: Yeah our number is part of a messaging service, but I was not able to edit the settings to disable the opt-out feature. The goal is when the user reply with opt-out keywords, it skips over Twilio's opt-out function. Twilio will do nothing but to pass the message to us via webhook, and we will scan the keywords and put the phone number in our opt-out list.

Comment: Oh, in that case you should get in touch with either your account manager or support. We can't fix this on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @philnash - hoping the following works well based on all this

```rb
rescue Twilio::REST::RestError => e
    if e.code == 21610
      user = User.find_by(phone_number: user_phone_number)
      user.update(marketing_list: false) if user
      puts "Updated user #{user_phone_number} to opted out due to Twilio 21610 error."
    else
      raise e
    end

...
```